# How to calculate the time complexity of snippet containing inner loops which may terminate at any point

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

How to calculate the time complexity of below snippet?

```
let count, barHeight, result = 1 << 31;
for(let i = 0; i < heights.length; i++) {
    count = 1;
    barHeight = heights[i];
    for(let j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (heights[j] >= barHeight) {
            count++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for(let k = i+1; k< heights.length; k++) {
        if (heights[k] >= barHeight) {
            count++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    result = Math.max(result, count*barHeight);
}
```

Basically this snippet is to calculate for any index `i`, calculate how many adjacent indexes of `heights` array are no less than `heights[i]`.

I am a bit confused how to calculate the time complexity in this case.
The 2 inner loops may stop at any point.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Huan, does my answer solve your question? If it does, could you please mark it as accept it? if it doesn't could you please let me know why that's the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quadratic `O(n^2)`.

When evaluating time complexity you should always look at the worst case scenario, unless there is an objective amortization that justifies that worst case to be amortized by all the other cases.

This algorithm is quadratic.